# WebRequest Proxy - 403 forbidden Error

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webrequest

I want to connect URL via proxy server but when I am using proxy and try to get response it returns (403) Forbidden .

Without proxy everything works .

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wikipedia.com");
        webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("41.217.193.6", 80);    
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        webRequest.Timeout = 9000;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();     /// <== The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string sResponseHTML = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            Clipboard.SetText(sResponseHTML);
    }
```

Comment: did you set the credentials for the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proxy ("41.217.193.6", 80) needs authentication. If you try a new proxy, the code above works. For example, at the time of writing, the following proxy works.

```
webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("200.61.168.141", 8080);
```